# Ошибка. Файлы отсутствуют

Tags: php

Я нуб в пхп, так что не бейте, если будет тупая ошибка. Я написал код:

```
<?php
$dir    = 'css';
$files1 = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
foreach ($files1 as $key ): 
?> 
<a href="<?=$key ?>" download="">скачать<?="<br />"?></a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Хочу, чтобы каждый файл в n-ной папке можно было скачать, но при скачивании в Мозиле ничего не выдает, а в Хроме пишет: "Ошибка. Файлы отсутствуют", я хз как это исправить, поэтому обращаюсь к вам..(с папками все хорошо, все файлы присутствуют)

Comment: естественно, путь то неправильный указан, хоть ты и думаешь, что правильный

Comment: @Jean-Claude а какой правильный?( Я поставил весь путь от диска до папки, все равно не пошло)

Comment: да, правильный = полный, и должны быть права на доступ

Comment: @Jean-Claude Хорошо, спасибо